# Best practice to handle big amount of events

Tags: javascript, events

im wondering if there is some really good way to handle big amount of JS events. I dont like id-based method - too many id's, bindings and some event need to be fired on several targets, so i need to give them different name and use something like this

```
$('#some-id').add('#some-id-another').click(...)
```

or classes. Somewhere i saw a really nice approach

```
<span data-cmd="menu">Open Menu First link</span>
.....some html
<span data-cmd="menu">Open Menu Second link</span>
<span data-cmd="settings">Setting</span>
<script>
//bind delegated click listeners to body
//get target's data
switch()
case "menu": do smtng
case "setting": do smtng
</script>
```

Seems very clear smooth and nice. What is the main disadvantages u guys can see? Much slower then id/class?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, I think you have two main solutions to handle a large amount of events and keep your code clean. The good news is that these solutions are not incompatible...

**1. Organize your code as a module**

```
var module = {
  init: function () {
    module.listeners();
  },
  listeners: function () {
    $('#myDiv').mouseover(module.handlers.divHover);
    $('button').click(module.handlers.buttonClick);
  },
  handlers: {
    divHover: function () {
      console.log('Div hovered!');
    },
    buttonClick: function () {
      console.log('Button clicked!');
    }
  }
};

$(document).ready(module.init);
```

**2. Use event delegation**

In JavaScript, you can use **bubbling** or **capture** to handle events. With jQuery, this is pretty straightforward...

Instead of doing this:

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
  console.log('Button clicked!');
});
```

You could do something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function () {
  console.log('Button clicked!');
});
```

Comment: Yep, the aproach i described in my first post uses delegation. The main advatage is to get rid of big amount of classes and id's. So i can create 1 class, 'click', for example, and $('body').on('click', '.click', function () {
  //get data-cmd, and execute cmd u need here
});. Is this looks fine or i just make simple thinks harder?

Comment: You could do so, indeed. Moreover, be aware that you can use the `event` object if you want to refine the behavior of your handler... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu', function() {
    //do something
});
```

This will create a single click handler on the document that will fire anytime you click on the page. However it will only execute the function if the click originated from an element with the class "menu".

The disadvantage is that every click on the page fires the handler. Shouldn't be an issue with click, but if your event was mouseIn then it would be.

The advantage is a single handler which less of a burden on the browser, certainly say compared to binding up say 500 separate handlers on individual elements.

Another advantage is if you are manipulating the DOM by replacing various sections. If you bind the handlers directly to the element then when replace an element, the handler will be lost. You would need to bind the handler again. Similarly if you add new element you would need to bind the handler at that point. However, if you bind the handler to the document in the onload event then you never have to worry about it again.

Comment: Yeah, but i would need to create as many $(document).on() as many different id's and classes for different purposes i have. So i want just get rid of bunch of id's and classes. "The disadvantage is that every click on the page fires the handler." - so i can just create 'click' class, for example, <span class="click" data-cmd="menu"> and 'case' cmd's.

Comment: @user1128677 Same thing works for `$(document).on('click', '[data-cmd="menu"]', function(e) {…});` if for some reason you don't like `id` and `class` attributes